# Meaning of "draw and hold together"

Tags: meaning, idiom-meaning

I am consulting Oxford online on [«gather»](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/gather) and couldn't understand item 6:

> Draw and hold together (fabric or a part of a garment) by running thread through it.

Searching Google, I see that "draw and hold together" some kind of expression. [One case](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=xlN2CgAAQBAJ&pg=PT869&lpg=PT869&dq=%22draw%20and%20hold%20together%22&source=bl&ots=IMp4Af_nWx&sig=8AqGSmWd-WzHA9zMjIHLcg3H7b4&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjf8La-rvzTAhVCjpAKHUCIBfEQ6AEIJjAA#v=onepage&q=%22draw%20and%20hold%20together%22&f=false):

> It is fitting that he who draws and holds together the physical and intellectual, should also draw and hold together the moral universe, drawing all men to himself ...

I have looked for this expression in Oxford online of Merriam-Webster Unabridged online but found no definition.

What does it mean?

Comment: What are the possible definitions of "draw"?

Comment: Check out [drawstring](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/drawstring) and [gathered skirt.](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/gathered+skirt)

Answer (score 1):

To draw and hold things together means to [draw (them together)] and [hold (them) together], or to collect and bind (or unite) them.

In your first example, one is explaining how to sew a gather, to [draw (together)] and [hold together] physical fabric. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gather_(sewing)

In your second example, one is using a more abstract meaning, to [draw (together)] and [hold together] certain philosophies; that is, to pull them close and keep them close (to one's heart and conscience) - to embrace and exemplify those philosophies.